# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException

Tags: java, date

I am parsing normal date into LocalDate formate.While converting I am getting One exception called.

> Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-01-12
>   00:00:00.0' could not be parsed at index 2    at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]    at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]

As I know I am getting the same formate.So while converting I am getting this exception.Am I correct. If I am correct How to check the input is the same format or not.

This is my code:-

```
        DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT =  new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").toFormatter();
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(myClass.getDate, DATE_FORMAT);
        System.out.println(localDate.format(DATE_FORMAT));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern "dd/MM/yyyy" does not match your input. Use the pattern

"uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S" instead. And also important: You should not parse such an input to a `LocalDate` because your input has time information, too. A more edaquate type is `LocalDateTime`. Full example making a difference between given input (as indicated by your exception) and wished output:

```
DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT =
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").toFormatter();
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-01-12 00:00:00.0", DATE_FORMAT);
System.out.println(ldt); // 2017-01-12T00:00

System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"))); // 12/01/2017
```

Comment: Actually for the First time saving there is not problem while updating It is throwing this kind of exception

Comment: the exact Input i am getting is 07/01/2017

Comment: @ravi No, "07/01/2017" cannot be your input of your parse-routine if we follow your stacktrace mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience I am Getting the input is exactly as I mentioned

Comment: May I know How to Check the format of date with the already existed date

Comment: Within context of `java.time`-library, you can only check a date to match an expected pattern if you parse it and catch the possible exception and then reparse it with another pattern. Not very elegant (and a regression compared with other time libs) but cannot be avoided here.

Answer (score 0):

this pattern **appendPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")** can not format this string
**2017-01-12 00:00:00.0**

use instead **appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm.ss.S")**